# ActiveMQ - Automatically delete all messages from incative queue

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms, jmstemplate

I want to automatically delete all the messages from queues that where inactive for a specified amount of time (no new messaged was arrived on that time).

I don't want to explicitly empty the queue from code nor call purge explicitly as described [here](http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-purge-a-queue.html).

The configuration described [here](http://activemq.apache.org/delete-inactive-destinations.html) is also not appropriate to my case, since it deletes automatically only empty queues and my queues are not empty.

Is there any known ActiveMQ configuration that can do that task automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I never had such requierement and I don't know if such functionality exists in activemq, however, there is two options you might be interested with :

1) If you want to purge messages on inactive queues because they a no longer relevant, you could set the time to live on each messages ( setTimeToLive() method on producer side)

2) If you need that exact behavior, then you could develop your own plugin. Indeed activemq brokers are fairly extensible (see : http://activemq.apache.org/developing-plugins.html)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. That was a great help.